# ViewData.Expand развернуть уровень поэтапно по 1000 записей

Tags: delphi, devexpress

В БД имеется более 100 000 записей и когда я вызываю метод `tableview.ViewData.Expand(True)`, то программа уходит в статус "приложение не отвечает".

И пришла идея попробовать в метод `tableview.ViewData.Expand(True)` засылать циклом по 1000 записей и разворачивать те записи уровня detail которые в диапазоне этих записей. и так до последней записи!

Comment: А в чем состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: Вы уверены, что в природе существуют такие люди, которым действительно может понадобиться увидеть на экране все 100 000 записей?

Comment: @KromStern как заслать 1000 записей в expand()

Comment: @Yaant там фильтрация данных есть! но это нужно, что бы было

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что "верхний уровень" содержит данные, вычисляемые на основе вложенных? И эти данные вычисляются после загрузки всех записей?

Comment: @kami нет из верхнего уровня передаются параметры в запрос и на основании этого запроса строится второй подчиненный уровень

Comment: Допишите это в текст вопроса.

Comment: Я все-таки ратую за ленивую загрузку. Верхний уровень пусть формируется "сводным" запросом к базе и уже априори содержит все необходимые данные. А когда необходимо - пусть подгружаются вложенные данные. Аргументация простая - даже если вы сможете убрать фриз при подгрузке 100500 строк, приложение легко может свалиться с Out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Выхода на самом деле всего 2:

1. lazy-прогрузка узлов, т.е. данных фактически нет, пока не
   пользователь не раскроет ноду (как и советует @karmi).
2. Посмотреть как работает этот expand, и с помощью хаков переопределить его на свой метод, с добавлением параметра deptht, который ограничит глубину рекурсии. Заодно реализовать не блокируя UI, т.е. дергая ProcessMessages.

А ограничивать вывод по n записей не имеет смысла, вы же раскрываете ноду, и надо показать её всю. А вот Encand всей root до скольких-то там сотен тысяч записей, вот это не вариант вообще.